# Passing an array of ints from my HTML to Controller with Thymeleaf and SpringBoot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to pass an array of ints from my HTML back to my controller.

My flow is as follows:

I am retrieving data from an API and converting it to an Entity. All works fine.
However, I pass this to my HTML (Thymeleaf) and display some of the values to the User.

They then select one of the options and this is passed back to my Controller.
It is at this stage I lose the data I need.

In my Entity, I get the following data which I pass to the View (Example Below):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "MOVIE_ID")
private long movieId;

@JsonProperty("title")
@Column(name = "TITLE")
private String title;

@JsonProperty("overview")
@Column(name = "OVERVIEW", length = 2000)
private String overview;

@JsonProperty("popularity")
@Column(name = "POPULARITY")
private float popularity;

@JsonProperty("release_date")
@Column(name = "RELEASE_DATE")
private String releaseDate;

@JsonProperty("genre_ids")
private int[] genreIds;
```

Then in my view, I display some values and hide the ids I dont need to display so that I can pass them back to my controller:

```
        <form action = "#" th:action="@{/saveMovie}" method="post" th:object="${movie}">
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${movie.title}"></td>
            <td th:text="${movie.releaseDate}"></td>
            <td th:text="${movie.overview}"></td>
            <input type="hidden" id="title" name="title" th:value="*{title}"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="overview" name="overview" th:value="*{overview}"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="popularity" name="popularity" th:value="*{popularity}"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="releaseDate" name="releaseDate" th:value="*{releaseDate}"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="genreIds" name="genreIds" th:value="*{genreIds}"/>
            <td>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </form>
```

Controller to handle the call:

```
@PostMapping("/saveMovie") public String saveMovie(@ModelAttribute(value = "movie") Movie movie)
```

UPDATE***
Adding the GET/POST controllers that currently interact with this page:

```
@GetMapping("/searchMovie")
public String searchMovie(final Model model){

    List<Movie> returnedMovies = new ArrayList<>();

    model.addAttribute("movies", returnedMovies);

    return "Search";
}


@PostMapping("/searchMovie")
public String searchMovieInTMDB(@RequestParam(value = "movieName", required = true) String movieName,
                                Model model){

    List<Movie> returnedMovies = service.searchMovies(movieName);

    model.addAttribute("movies", returnedMovies);

    return "Search";
}

@PostMapping("/saveMovie")
public String saveMovie(@ModelAttribute(value = "movie") Movie movie){

    service.storeMovie(movie);

    return "WORK_IN_PROGRESS";
}
```

However, when I pass the values back to the controller I get the conversion error:

```
[Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int[]' for property 'genreIds']
```

I have changed it to String[] to test this works and error goes away but then I am presented with another problem in that it is converted to :
[String Value Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPk64.png)

The only way I have found to pass the object back is by using the input tag and hiding them.
It converts the float fine, but can't handle the array of ints.

Is there a better way to pass objects back and forth between the controller using Thymeleaf or is there another attribute I can use to pass the array back and forth?

Thanks in advance

Conor

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/saveMovie}" method="post"
    th:object="${movie}">
    <tr>
        <td th:text="${movie.title}"></td>
        <td th:text="${movie.releaseDate}"></td>
        <td th:text="${movie.overview}"></td>
        <input type="hidden" id="title" name="title" th:value="*{title}" />
        <input type="hidden" id="overview" name="overview"
            th:value="*{overview}" />
        <input type="hidden" id="popularity" name="popularity"
            th:value="*{popularity}" />
        <input type="hidden" id="releaseDate" name="releaseDate"
            th:value="*{releaseDate}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="genreIds" th:field="*{genreIds}" />
        <td>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>

@PostMapping("/saveMovie")
public String saveMovie(@ModelAttribute Movie movie) {
    System.err.println(movie);
    return "redirect:/movies";
}

@GetMapping("/movies")
public String getBooks(Model model) {
    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.setGenreIds(new int[] {4,5,6,7,8});
    model.addAttribute("movie", movie);
    return "movie";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. Unfortunately it did not work. Anytime I update it to 

th:field 

I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'movie' available as request attribute

Comment: can you post your get controller method which is returning themeleaf template page.

Comment: I have added the controller methods there now. Thank you for your quick responses :-)

Comment: Hi, the th:field didn't work for me, I got the binding error above

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You should send numbers as List to the controller.

```
@PostMapping("/saveMovie")
public String saveMovie(@RequestBody List<Movie> movies){
    movieService.function_name(movies);
    return "movies";
}
```

Another way to do this is using **AJAX** call to the controller. Just need to collect numbers as list in javascript and through ajax you should send array as json to controller. In controller you will parse them